# Difference between String.isEmpty() and String.equals("")

Tags: java, string

I created a "Color Chooser" with three textboxes where the user defines rgb values.
To check if values entered are correct (only numbers between 0-255) I'm using the following:

```
public Color getColor() {
    if (tfRed.getText().equals("") || tfGreen.getText().equals("") || tfBlue.getText().equals("")) {
                return new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        if (tfRed.getText().matches("\\d+") && tfGreen.getText().matches("\\d+") && tfBlue.getText().matches("\\d+")) {
            // ...
        } else {
            return new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm asking: is it better to use `String.isEmpty()`? I never found a satisfying answer and I've always wondered if there is any difference.

Comment: See this discussion, [Should I use string.isEmpty() or “”.equals(string)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321526/should-i-use-string-isempty-or-equalsstring)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think `isEmpty()` is a bit more efficient.  However a smart compiler may optimize the `equals("")` call anyway.  From the [OpenJDK source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java):

```
  671     public boolean isEmpty() {
  672         return count == 0;
  673     }

 1013     public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
 1014         if (this == anObject) {
 1015             return true;
 1016         }
 1017         if (anObject instanceof String) {
 1018             String anotherString = (String)anObject;
 1019             int n = count;
 1020             if (n == anotherString.count) {
 1021                 char v1[] = value;
 1022                 char v2[] = anotherString.value;
 1023                 int i = offset;
 1024                 int j = anotherString.offset;
 1025                 while (n-- != 0) {
 1026                     if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
 1027                         return false;
 1028                 }
 1029                 return true;
 1030             }
 1031         }
 1032         return false;
 1033     }
```

Also the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321526/should-i-use-string-isempty-or-equalsstring/3321548#3321548) on whether to use `str.isEmpty()` or `"".equals(str)` is spot on:

> The main benefit of `"".equals(s)` is you don't *need* the null check (`equals` will check its argument and return `false` if it's null), which you seem to not care about. If you're not worried about `s` being null (or are otherwise checking for it),  I would definitely use `s.isEmpty()`; it shows exactly what you're checking, you care whether or not `s` is empty, not whether it equals the empty string

Answer (score 16):

Yes, use `String.isEmpty()`. It is cleaner (semantically) (performance is also slightly better, but that would be unnoticable) If the instance can be null, use commons-lang `StringUtils.isEmpty(string)`

Answer (score 12):

Since `isEmpty()` checks if the length of the `String` is 0 and `""` is the *only* `String` with length 0, each `String` for which `isEmpty()` returns `true` would also return `true` to `.equals("")`. So technically, *they do the same thing*.

There might be a minimal difference in performance, but I wouldn't bother about that at all (I'd be very surprised if it were noticeable in production code).

Another difference is if you wrote `"".equals(someString)`, then it would be "`null`-safe". In other words: if `someString` was `null`, this construct would simply evaluate to `false` and not throw a `NullPointerException`. If, however, you have `someString.equals("")` then this would *not* apply.

The *most important* difference is how it's read: `isEmpty()` makes the intention *very* clear: you want to treat empty strings differently. `.equals("")` is ever so slightly *less* clear ("if that string equals that other string, that happens to be empty").

Comment: In addition to above answer 

`String.equals("")` is bit slower than just an `isEmpty()` call. Strings store a count variable initialized in the constructor, since Strings are immutable.

`isEmpty()` compares the count variable to 0, while equals will check the type, string length, and then iterate over the string for comparison if the sizes match.

`isEmpty()` will actually do a lot less! and that's a good thing.

Comment: Yes I was searching for this "".isEquals(someString) or "".isEqualsIgnoreCase(someString) will not throw NullPointerException. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Typically, I like to use equals but in reverse, ie:

```
"".equals(someString);
```

Null-safe :)

But yeah, isEmpty() is a simpler operation but not so much that I see it making any significant performance contribution (unless you are writing embedded real-time stuff).

Comment: But if you reverse it, despite avoiding NPE, it may have an unexpected behavior, where null would be validated as false instead of true, thinking about the valid String scenario...

Answer (score 4):

With `myString.equals("")`, first the compiler creates an String object (it is equivalent to `myString.equals(new String(""))`.

So, isEmpty() should be a better option (although equals("") is very popular).

Comment: String literals are usually loaded when the class loads and "" is almost guaranteed to exist already.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey what do you mean by "loaded". Singletons?

Comment: it isn't equivallent to `new String("")`. `""` is interned and already exists in the string pool.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, it is. For `isEmpty()`, only the internal metadata of the string has to be looked at (e.g., it's length). For the comparison, you would expect slightly more case differentiations happening.

In practice, it does not matter. You would not observe the speed difference.

Rule of thump: Use the method that is best understood / most readable by the programmer. If it is a test for empty string, I think `isEmpty()` fits that purpose best.

Answer (score 4):

`isEmpty()` is faster because it only compares the `length` integer field in `String` class to `0` while comparing to an empty string will at best compare references (similar speed) and at worst - run a loop with 0 iterations.

But the biggest difference is readability - `isEmpty()` is shorter and easier to grasp. BTW I wish there was an `isBlank()` shorthand for `.trim().isEmpty()`...

Comment: Since JAVA 11  ```String.isBlank()``` was added.

Answer (score 4):

One more reason using `myString.equals("")` or `myString.length() == 0` is that `String#isEmpty()` method was introduced in Java 1.6.

So arguments to do not use `String#isEmpty()` can be compatibility reasons with previous versions of Java.

Answer (score 3):

It's partly a matter of history and legacy uses. **`isEmpty()` was only added in JDK 6:**

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if, and only if, {@link #length()} is <tt>0</tt>.
 *
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if {@link #length()} is <tt>0</tt>, otherwise
 * <tt>false</tt>
 *
 * @since 1.6
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
```

Before that, everyone compared with `""` to see if an String was empty or not. Old habits die hard, so loads of people keep using the `""` comparison.

Of course, as mentioned by someone else already, if you use `"".equals(someString)` then it's automatically null safe. Many people combine the idea of isEmpty with null safeness, by making a [static isEmpty method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: *"Before that, everyone compared with "" to see if an String was empty or not."* - not everyone.  Some people used `length() == 0`

Answer (score 2):

`isEmpty` was only introduced in 1.6.  Check *Since* tag in [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29).

Therefore, if you are compiling for 1.5 and lower `equals("")` is your only choice.

However, if version compatibility is not of your concern, I would use `isEmpty`.  As Bozho pointed out it is semantically cleaner ( and a bit faster ).

Answer (score 0):

I had always used `.isEmpty()`... until today, when I discovered that it does not exist in Java 5.

So :

- In Java 6 and newer, we have the choice, and I recommend using `.isEmpty()`, it is easier to write and clearer to read.
- In Java 5 and older we have to use `.equals("")`.