# java : Handling Null check through a Combination

Tags: java

I am able to handle null check on a String with this below piece of code

```
 if (acct != null && !acct.isEmpty()|| !acct.equals(""))
```

what i mean from the above code is , if

1. Accountid is not equal to null And
2. Accountid length is greater than 0
   (These two is a combination of checks )

Or

1. Accountid  is not equal to ""

Does my code satisfy these combination i mentioned above , or do i need to add any brackets ?? to satisfy the combination ( first 1 and 2 ) i mentioned above ??

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you test it yourself?

Comment: So you mean , this should be this way if ((acct != null && !acct.isEmpty())|| !acct.equals(""))

Comment: Note that you will get a `NullPointerException` when `acct` is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, and is always evaluated before or, i.e.  your code is the same as

```
if ((acct != null && !acct.isEmpty()) || !acct.equals(""))
```

However, logically it does not make sense to me.  Do you really need the last part? Isn't "acct.isEmpty()" the same as "acct.equals(""))" in this specific instance?

Answer (score 2):

`isEmpty()` and `.equals("")` are exactly the same condition. And your test will throw a NullPointerException if `acct` is null.

I don't understand exactly which test you want to make, but this one is wrong. Think about it once again, and implement a unit test to test all the cases:

- null string,
- empty string,
- not empty string.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question framed by you, it should have brackets as below

```
if ((acct != null && !acct.isEmpty()) || !("".equals(acct) ))
```

After the || operator, the code is changed which will avoid facing NullPointerException when acct is NULL.

This SO answer explains more about using "".equals().

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3321548/713414

Comment: I kind of know what you're saying but as others have pointed out, this will still cause a NullPointerException. The bracketing means the test on the other side of the '||' will be executed whether 'acct!=null' or not.