# JAVA: maps and return type of Map.get

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap of key and value both of String type.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
//put the key-values now
```

I want to check for null or emptiness of the value of a particular key. Referencing the discussion  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321526/should-i-use-string-isempty-or-equalsstring), I do it as:

```
if("".equals(map.get("keyName")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Is it valid?
As the return type of Map.get is Object, so do I need to check it like this:

```
if("".equals(map.get("keyName").toString()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

But toString() gives null pointer exception if it is null. So, what is the right way to do it?
Yes, I'm a beginner.

Comment: it is better for you to check map first. `if(map!=null){ //yourcode}`. Nullpointer happen because map is null, so when you use map.get("keyName") it returns that exception

Comment: Show the declaration of your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
String val = map.get("keyName");
if(val != null && !"".equals(val)){
    // val is not null and is not empty
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask, why can't we just perform `"".equals(val)` check and nothing else?

Comment: @AkeshwarJha you can. but `"".equals(val)` will return false in case if value is `null` or has some value (not blank).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use StringUtils from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/):

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(map.get("keyName")){
  // Do something
}
```

See the JavaDoc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this -

```
if(map.get("keyName").equals(null) || map.get("keyName").equals("")){
     //Failed to insert code
}
```