# Why doesn't this if condition work?

Tags: java, swing

I created this code to check whether the text field of calculator has any content. If content is present in the text field, then it should display `"."`. Otherwise, it should display `"0."` in the text field. The problem is that the if condition always evaluates to false.

```
private void dotActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    String dott=display.getText();
    if(dott==null)
    {
        display.setText(display.getText()+"0.");
    }
    else
    {
        display.setText(display.getText()+dot.getText());   
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty text field returns `""`, not `null`. `null` is never returned from `getText`.

Comment: Exactly. Replace `if (dott == null)` with `if (dott.isEmpty())`, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

The string will be `""`, not null. Use `dott.isEmpty()` to see if `dott` has no contents. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321526/should-i-use-string-isempty-or-equalsstring) is another post with more details on the difference between `.compareTo("")` and `.isEmpty().`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do :

```
if(dott.equals(""))
```

Comment: As per @Zircon's comment, I doubt it will ever be null, in this case.

Comment: `dott.isEmpty()` should also work. It's mostly a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

try this String method:

```
if(dott.isEmpty())
    //your code
```

or you can also use:

```
if(dott.compareTo("")==0)
    // your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 String dott = ...;
 dott.isEmpty();
```

or

```
 dott.equals("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dott=display.getText();
if(dott==null) // original code; should use isEmpty()
{
    display.setText(display.getText()+"0.");
}
```

But you already know that display.getText() is empty, so why execute it again? Same for the "else" clause - you already know the value. So you should just write:

```
String dott=display.getText();
if(dott.isEmpty()) {
    display.setText("0.");
} else {
    display.setText(dott+dot.getText());   
}
```

Or more concise:

```
   String dott=display.getText();
   String text = dott.isEmpty() ? "0." : dot.getText();
   display.setText(text);
```

or even:

```
   String dott=display.getText();
   display.setText( dott.isEmpty() ? "0." : dot.getText() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace if(dott==null) by

> if(dott.equals(""))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringUtils` of apache if you want. Link  : `https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html`

```
  private void dotActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String dott=display.getText();
        if( StringUtils.isEmpty(dott))
        {
            display.setText(display.getText()+"0.");
        }
        else
        {
            display.setText(display.getText()+dot.getText());   
        }
    }
```