# Java: error while outputing to server on button click event

Tags: java, javafx

I am having a problem with Java wich is i cannot use the button click event to send any kind of data through the output stream, because it gives me a NullPointerException. This code works fine if used out of the button click event, however when i try it in this particular section it will catch that exception.
Would apreciate if someone could detect my error and if possible explain what happen so i won't do the same mistake over and over again.

Code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource().equals(loginButton)) {
        if(!userField.getText().isEmpty()){
            if(!passwordField.getText().isEmpty()){
                try {
                    os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeBytes("login\n" + userField.getText() + "\n" + passwordField.getText());
                    System.out.print("Sucess data sent");
                } catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=51005:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\vasco\IdeaProjects\Learning\out\production\Learning" sample.Main
C:\Users\vasco
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Main.actionPerformed(Main.java:94)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: could you post here the complete exception message?

Comment: I edited the post and added it

Comment: which line is line 94?

Comment: Its the os = writebytes. If i remove this code and place it anywhere else that doesnt use button events it works. I tried also placing it in a void and calling the void through that event, result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `NullPointerException` error is being caused or could be caused from `if(!userField.getText().isEmpty())` or `if(!passwordField.getText().isEmpty())`. That's because the `isEmpty()` function could return `null`. Instead use `if(!userField.getText().equals(""))` and `if(!passwordField.getText().equals(""))` although it's a bit slower you know it will never return a null as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321526/should-i-use-string-isempty-or-equalsstring).

Other cause of the exception could be the initiallization of the socket variable, replace `os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());` for `os = new DataOutputStream(new Socket("Your IP address", int port).getOutputStream());`

As a sidenote, instead of using `sendBytes("");` function, use `sendUTF("")` it has the next benefits:

- The null byte '\u0000' is encoded in 2-byte format rather than 1-byte so that the encoded strings never have embedded nulls.
- Only the 1-byte, 2-byte, and 3-byte formats are used.
- [Supplementary characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) are represented in the form of surrogate pairs.

Select as answer if it'd helped and if you have a question or it's still not working tell me and I'll solve it.

Comment: Hum i don't think it is because of the isEmpty statements, otherwise it wouldnt get past that part, however i changed it because it could at some point give me an error. Also i made a mistake the line 94 is actually the os = new DataOutputStream...  and that line is the one giving NullPointerException

Comment: @VascoFerreira So the problem might be in the Socket variable, could you post the initiallization and declaration of the socket variable?

Comment: I found the problem, the variables were not being declared as static. Dumb move of mine. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: @VascoFerreira check out if now it corrects your problem (although you already solved it changing the variables to static) and if it does select it as answer please.