# Validate name to not be blank

Tags: java

I wrote a method that asks the user to input a name, but I don't want it equal to the `compName` and I don't want the user's input to be blank. I have `humanName.equals("")` but that will only make sure that the name isn't "". It could still be one or more blank spaces. I need there to be atleast one character there. I can't figure out how to go about doing this.

```
public String getHumanName(String compName){
  System.out.println("Enter a name for the human player: ");
  String humanName = scan.nextLine();
  while(humanName.equals(compName) || humanName.equals("")){
        System.out.println("The human player cannot have the same name as the computer player or be blank. Enter a new name for the human player: ");
        humanName = scan.nextLine();
  }
  return humanName;
}
```

Comment: look up the `trim()` method of string.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Ah got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) to eliminate extra spaces at the beginning or the end of a string.

```
while(humanName.equals(compName) || humanName.trim().equals("")){
```

Comment: `equals("")` can be replaced by `isEmpty()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321526/should-i-use-string-isempty-or-equalsstring.

Comment: I would to it this way: `"".equals(input)`, because hardcoded String "" is never NULL. `.equals(null)` doesn´t throw a exception.

Comment: @LenglBoy if I wrote `"".equals(humanName.trim())` and `humanName` was null, it would have thrown an NPE anyway.

Comment: damn - it´s monday. You´re right. But then do first check the input not to be null and then values/empty. `string != null && !string.trim().isEmpty() && !string.equals(computerName)`

Comment: @LenglBoy by the time `humanName` *may* be null, the scanner would have thrown an exception already and the code would be outta here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) and `equals`.

```
while (humanName.equals(compName) || humanName == null || "".equals(humanName.trim()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trim() method of strings in Java to remove leading to trailing spaces of a String.

```
public String getHumanName(String compName){
  System.out.println("Enter a name for the human player: ");
  String humanName = scan.nextLine();

  humanName = humanName.trim();

  while(humanName.equals(compName) || humanName.equals("")){
        System.out.println("The human player cannot have the same name as the computer player or be blank. Enter a new name for the human player: ");
        humanName = scan.nextLine();

        humanName = humanName.trim();
  }
  return humanName;
}
```

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to manages it.

- [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) the input so blanks will be removed and you just need to check against `EMPTY`
- Use the hibernate validator with `@NotBlank` - working for java SE and EE.